# Rotate objects as a group in Raphael

Tags: javascript, canvas, raphael

I'm new to Raphael and I'm trying to do two circles move in circular orbits related to the center of the canvas.

Here I made ellipses to illustrate the case. The black point is the center of the canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/QCSb9/

I used set() to group the circles but when trying to rotate them, they rotate using their own centers individually, I thought that grouping the circles the new geometry of the group would change, becoming the black point the center of the group.

How can I rotate these circles continuously as one object.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$().ready(function(){

                var paper = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);
                paper.rect(0, 0, 640, 480, 10).attr({fill: "#fff", stroke: "none"});  
                paper.circle(320, 240,  1).attr({"fill":"#000000","stroke-width":0});                

                var circles = paper.set();
                circles.push(
                    paper.ellipse(200, 240, 30, 25),
                    paper.ellipse(440, 240, 30, 25)
                );

                circles.attr({"fill":"#e00000","stroke-width":0});

                var anim = Raphael.animation({"transform":"r360"},2000);
                circles.animate(anim.repeat(Infinity));
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: It was a matter of specifying the center of rotation to **"r360,320,240"**:

```
var anim = Raphael.animation({"transform":"r360,320,240"},2000);
```

rotate() is deprecated but explains the parameters admitted:

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.rotate

Here the example corrected on jsfiddle.net

http://jsfiddle.net/SW3sP/1/